# android studio byte[] for UDP is redudant

Tags: java, android

I just want to send data to another device (PC) using UDP  by clicking on a button. So I made a method for it in which I put the UDP code and made a relation when button is clicked. But according to the IDE, the byte which contains the String data I want to send is not well created.

Here's the code:

```
String argv = "WhatISend";
int port = 9268;
byte[] buffer= new byte[argv.lenght()];


try {

    InetAddress server = InetAddress.getByName("172.16.19.14");
    buffer = argv.getBytes();
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    DatagramPacket udp_emission = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, server, port);
    socket.send(udp_emission);
    socket.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Fail socket");
}
```

the problem is on "byte[] buffer= new byte[size];"

Comment: What problem? 'not well created' how?

Comment: Well I got "Variable 'buffer 'initializer new byte[argv.length()]' is redundant"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the wording of your question, it sounds like you want `buffer` to contain the characters of the original string.  However, the `byte` array actually *does not* contain the string data.  The code you have shown us just creates a `byte` array that has the same length as the input string.  You have not assigned the individual characters over to the `buffer`.

What you probably want is this:

```
buffer = argv.getBytes();
```

For more information, see [`String.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29).

Comment: I got this done in my code, but I got "Variable 'buffer 'initializer new byte[argv.length()]' is redundant"

Comment: @user4791873 Yes.  It is redundant because `argv.getBytes()` both *creates* and assigns the byte array for you.  So you don't have to initialize `buffer` before you call `argv.getBytes()`.  Otherwise, your're first creating a blank array and then later tossing it away and replacing it with a new one when you call `argv.getBytes()`.

Comment: So the line where you declare `buffer` should just be `byte[] buffer;`

Comment: @user4791873 Did this work for you?  If so, could you please accept the answer?